# Eigen refuses colum-major fixed-size matrices with an single row

Tags: matrix, eigen, eigen3

There is a static assert in Eigen:

```
EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT((EIGEN_IMPLIES(MaxRowsAtCompileTime==1 && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=1, (Options&RowMajor)==RowMajor)
```

which prevents from having column major fixed size matrices with 1 row:

```
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 3, Eigen::ColMajor> m;
```

I don't really understand why Eigen does not let the user do that (which by the way is quite annoying in my code design)... What is the point of the major order for a 1D array?

Thanks!!

Comment: See this discussion: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=416

Comment: Could you explain why not using a rowvector (rowmajor)?

Comment: Or use a Matrix<double,3,1> and transpose when needed? Maybe you could post a situation to justify your problem?

Comment: @MFnx The problem arises, e.g., in generic code, if `n` is a template parameter and you need a `Matrix<double, n, 3, ColMajor>`. You'll always need to write some `? ColMajor:RowMajor` into your matrices.